# jq cannot convert string to int in bash

Tags: bash, jq

I'm working on generating a new JSON payload to update Consul with a MSSQL database service location.

When I call jq like this:

```sh
mssql_svc_ip=$(kubectl get svc/mssql-linux -o 'jsonpath={.spec.clusterIP}')
mssql_svc_port=$(kubectl get svc/mssql-linux -o 'jsonpath={.spec.ports[0].port}')

jq -n -r --arg MSSQL_IP $mssql_svc_ip --arg MSSQL_PORT $mssql_svc_port '{
    "Datacenter": "dev",
    "Node": "database",
    "Address": $MSSQL_IP,
    "Service": {
        "Service": "mssql-dev",
        "Port": $MSSQL_PORT
        }
}'
```

It produces the proper structure:

```sh
{
  "Datacenter": "dev",
  "Node": "database",
  "Address": "10.43.192.146",
  "Service": {
    "Service": "mssql-dev",
    "Port": "1433"
  }
}
```

I need to convert the `Service.Port` field from a string to an integer as that's what the Consul API requires. I can do that with `tonumber`, like this:

```sh
mssql_svc_ip=$(kubectl get svc/mssql-linux -o 'jsonpath={.spec.clusterIP}')
mssql_svc_port=$(kubectl get svc/mssql-linux -o 'jsonpath={.spec.ports[0].port}')

jq -n -r --arg MSSQL_IP $mssql_svc_ip --arg MSSQL_PORT $mssql_svc_port '{
    "Datacenter": "dev",
    "Node": "database",
    "Address": $MSSQL_IP,
    "Service": {
        "Service": "mssql-dev",
        "Port": tonumber($MSSQL_PORT)
        }
}'
```

However, when I try and convert the `$MSSQL_PORT` variable to a number, I get this error:

```sh
jq: error: tonumber/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 7:
        "Port": tonumber($MSSQL_PORT)                
jq: 1 compile error
```

At first I thought it was an assignment error and the variables weren't being passes as arguments properly, but I've tried a couple iterations and I still get the same error. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misusing the `tonumber` filter.  Based on [the documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tonumber) it looks like the syntax would be something like:

```
jq -n -r --arg MSSQL_IP "$mssql_svc_ip" --arg MSSQL_PORT "$mssql_svc_port" '{
    "Datacenter": "dev",
    "Node": "database",
    "Address": $MSSQL_IP,
    "Service": {
        "Service": "mssql-dev",
        "Port": ($MSSQL_PORT|tonumber)
        }
}'
```

And indeed, if `$msssql_svc_ip` is `10.43.192.146` and `$mssql_svc_port` is 
`1433`, that gets me:

```
{
  "Datacenter": "dev",
  "Node": "database",
  "Address": "10.43.192.146",
  "Service": {
    "Service": "mssql-dev",
    "Port": 1433
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, Inian beat me by a few seconds, but that's because I was hunting down a link to the docs :).

Comment: Ahhhhh okay I thought it was a function, not a filter. Changing the syntax to be a filter as you referenced solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Would you object to an edit fixing up the shell quoting? (That is, making it `"$mssql_svc_ip"` and `"$mssql_svc_port"` on the first line).

Comment: I've gone ahead and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to pass the number in with `--argjson` instead of `--arg`:

```
$ jq -n -r --argjson foo 12 '{"foo":$foo}'
{
  "foo": 12
}
```

This seems simpler than using `tonumber`